# get list of all calendars of user. Not just the ones they chose to list on their google calendar page

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

How to get the list of *all* calendars of user. Not just the ones they chose to [list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#calendar_and_calendar_list) on their google calendar page.

Apparently, google disapproves of (inhibits!) getting a list of **all** of the user's calendars. Only the calendars that the user chose to make visible on their google calendar page are iterable via `service.calendarList().list().execute()`.
There's no equivalent for `service.calendars()`.
How am I supposed to get the id of a calendar the user has chosen to hide from their google calendar page?

Answer (score 1):

You cant.

The only option open to you is as you said service.calendarList().list().execute() which does not contain all of the calendars that a user has access to just the ones that have been added to calendar list.

Comment: But what's the idea? Why? And why do you have to figure it out by not finding the respective obvious function in the API? Instead of explicitly stating in the docs that this particular use case was omitted purposefully, indicating the reason?

Comment: Sorry i cant tell you why google does things.  I am sure they have a reason. All i can tell you is what is and is not possible though the api.   Developers dont document whats not possible if they did then the documents would be huge.  The only thing thats documented is what is possible (if your lucky).    And every edge case isnt going to be documented either.

Comment: Thank you, @DalmTo. Let me reword my question: How do I find a user's secondary calendar if they chose to hide it from their list of calendars on their google calendar page?

Comment: you will need to ask them

Comment: Have you already tried the showHidden=true request parameter on the calendarList.list()

Comment: @luc calendarList explicitly refers to the list of calendars the user has chosen to display and *not* his exhaustive list of calendars.

Comment: @luc by ask them i mean personally contact them and as they to add the calendar to either list or supply a form for them to submit additional calendar ids in your application.  There is no automatic way for you to find these calendars though the API.  This will require manual intervention on your part.